# Sort directory by last modified

Tags: raku

I'd like to sort a directory by the files that were last modified in raku. I'm getting the list of files like this:

```
"directory/".IO.dir;
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`.dir`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir) returns a [sequence](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq) of [`IO::Path`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path#Methods) objects.

The `IO::Path` object has a [`.modified`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path#method_modified) method that returns the [`Instant`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Instant) the directory entry was modified.

Combine the all of this:

```
say "$_: $_.modified.DateTime()" for "lib".IO.dir.sort(*.modified);
```

And you get a list of files in the "lib" directory, with their modification [`DateTime`](https://docs.raku.org/type/DateTime) in ascending order.

To get it in descending order, either use `-*.modified`, or call `.reverse` on the result.

As to sort performance: when you call [`sort`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List#routine_sort) with a Callable that accepts a single argument, it will do a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) for you under the hood.